# OAuth - Read the generated Access token and add cookie in response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am using OAuth in ASP.NET Web Api to return access token to the caller of the application.

I have inherited my OAuth provider class from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and once the user is authenticated inside the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` function, I want to read the generated access token, create it's hash with some salt value and then add the created hash into a cookie.

Below is the simplified definition of my `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` function.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");     
        return;
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    //Add claims required on client side.
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

    //Generate the token behind the scene for given ticket
    context.Validated(ticket);        
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    SetCsrfCookie(context);
}

private void SetCsrfCookie(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{        
    var accessToken = "<READ THE GENERATED ACCESS TOKEN HERE>";      //<------ How?
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)) return;

    var csrfToken = Helper.GetHash(accessToken);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken, new CookieOptions {HttpOnly = false});
}
```

I am facing two issues here.

1. First one is how to read the generated access token in the `SetCsrfCookie` function in the code above.
2. Generated cookie is not received on the client side.

I know its possible to intercept the response in a some `OwinMiddleware` inherited class and then I may be able to generate the required cookie and attach to the response but first I have not tried that and secondly, it seems better option to handle this case inside my OAuth provider class as some people suggest that deriving from the `OwinMiddleware` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the cookie issue by adding the below line of code on angular side

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

On the Web Api side I just set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header to `true` inside the `WebApiConfig.Register` method like below:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ALLOWED_ORIGIN"], "*", "*")
{
    SupportsCredentials = true
};
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

This solved my cookie problem.

For accessing the generated access token I inherited a class from `OwinMiddleware` and inside the Invoke function I access the response body to read the access token like below:

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var path = context.Request.Path;

    var stream = context.Response.Body;
    var buffer = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = buffer;

    await Next.Invoke(context);

    var reqStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
    reqStream.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    var data = reqStream.ReadToEnd();

    if (path.Equals(new PathString("/token"),StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
        var responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();            
        //check if the response body contains access token if so then do your processing
    }

    buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await buffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```